# Simple grammar checker program - optimal data structure

Tags: javascript, parsing, data-structures

I want to created a simple game for English that checks someone's sentences. They are able to construct their sentence using a fixed set of words from a word bank.

The word bank might be something scrambled like:

`[want, eat, I, hi, to]`

Then they'd create their sentence in the correct order:

`hi I want to eat.`

I asked this question on [English SO](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290615/general-grammar-rules-for-grammar-checker) as it originally pertained to grammatical questions- the question has evolved into more of a data structures question. You can read more about it at that link. My original thought to check sentence grammar using a set of generic English rules seemed like it could quickly grow too complex. It was recommended I just match using hard coded checks, shown below.

Before I further define these checks, I was wondering if a better data structure/method was known to check grammar for this purpose.

```
  if (input === the_answer) {
    msg = correct!
  } else {
    msg = 'Try again: ' + this.grammarRules(input, the_answer)); 
  }

Language_System.prototype.grammarRules = function(input, answer) {

   var grammar_hints = {
     quest1 : {
       task1 : [
         'The subject, Bob, needs to be first',
         'The phrase is Hello there'
       ]
     } 
   };

   var grammar_rules = {

     quest1 : {
       task1 : function (input, answer) {
         var error = -1;
         if (input[0] !== answer[0]) {
           error = 0;
         } else if (input.indexOf('hello') > input.indexOf('there')) {
           error = 1;
         }
         return grammar_hints.quest1.task1[error];
       }
     }

  };

  return grammar_rules.Lee.quest1.task1(input, answer);    

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you'd consider a more declarative approach:
- define a standard `quest` structure
- define a standard `task` structure with generic input formats
- define generic validators and re-use them

You started on the right path with the `grammar_hints` object, but I would actually put all the properties portraying to one task in the same object.

Suggestion:

```
var quests = [
    {
        name: 'Quest 1',
        tasks: [
            {
                name: 'Task 1',
                solution: 'hi I want to eat',
                validators: [
                    validators.first('hi'),
                    validators.verbAfterNoun('want', 'I'),
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

You will be able to re-use a lot of the validators in multiple tasks so you want them to be as generic as possible, here is one example:

```
var validators = {
    first: function (input, term) {
        if (input[0] !== term) {
            return 'The sentence needs to start with: ' + term;
        }
    },

    verbAfterNoun: function (input, verb, noun) {
        if (input.indexOf(verb) < input.indexOf(noun)) {
            return 'The verb, ' + verb + ', needs to come after the noun ' + noun;
        }
    }
};
```

Now because you want to have a declarative format (I went with actually initializing the validators with their input and passing the result in the `validators` array), we would need a validator factory that takes a generic validator and returns a helper method that can be re-used with only the input. This will help us down the line so our testing framework won't need to know how many inputs to pass to each of the validator callbacks

```
// This is a factory method that applies the given callback (with the given arguments)
function makeValidator (fn) {
    return function inputFN () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return function validate (input) {
            return fn.apply(null, [input].concat(args));
        }
    }
}

// Apply the makeValidator() method on all the validators
for (var key in validators) {
    validators[key] = makeValidator(validators[key]);
}
```

And finally we also want a standard way of checking our tasks against input:

```
// This method provides the generic validation framework for any task given any input
function validate (task, input) {
    var wordList = input.split(' ');

    if (input === task.solution) return {success: true, errors: []};

    var errors = [];
    task.validators.forEach(function (fn) {
        var error = fn(wordList);
        if (error) errors.push(error);
    });
    return {success: false, errors: errors};
}
```

And some examples:

```
var task = quests[0].tasks[0];
console.log(validate(task, 'hi I want to eat'));
console.log(validate(task, 'I want to eat hi'));
console.log(validate(task, 'hi want I to eat'));
console.log(validate(task, 'want I to eat hi'));
```

**Putting it all together:**

```js
// This is a factory method that applies the given callback (with the given arguments)
function makeValidator (fn) {
    return function inputFN () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return function validate (input) {
            return fn.apply(null, [input].concat(args));
        }
    }
}

var validators = {
    first: function (input, term) {
        if (input[0] !== term) {
            return 'The sentence needs to start with: ' + term;
        }
    },

    verbAfterNoun: function (input, verb, noun) {
        if (input.indexOf(verb) < input.indexOf(noun)) {
            return 'The verb, ' + verb + ', needs to come after the noun ' + noun;
        }
    }
};

// Apply the makeValidator() method on all the validators
for (var key in validators) {
    validators[key] = makeValidator(validators[key]);
}

var quests = [
    {
        name: 'Quest 1',
        tasks: [
            {
                name: 'Task 1',
                solution: 'hi I want to eat',
                validators: [
                    validators.first('hi'),
                    validators.verbAfterNoun('want', 'I'),
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
];

// This method provides the generic validation framework for any task given any input
function validate (task, input) {
    var wordList = input.split(' ');

    if (input === task.solution) return {success: true, errors: []};

    var errors = [];
    task.validators.forEach(function (fn) {
        var error = fn(wordList);
        if (error) errors.push(error);
    });
    return {success: false, errors: errors};
}

function printTask (input) {
    var task = quests[0].tasks[0];
    var result = validate(task, input);
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div><b>checking:</b> ' + input + '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre><hr />';
}

// Lets look at some examples
printTask('I want to eat hi');
printTask('hi want I to eat');
printTask('want I to eat hi');
printTask('hi I want to eat');
```

Comment: This is awesome and right inline with what I was looking for. Actually, I started doing generic word passing by part of speech right after I posted lol. This is awesome!

Comment: so, instead of initializing each validator in `validators` as a function, I would create them dynamically with `makeValidator` right?

Comment: pretty much, yes. it makes it easier to work/understand if the validators are stateless functions: they take in all the arguments and return the same result for the same input. The `makeValidator` helper just allows you to easily re-use validators while also basically hard-coding their arguments to each individual case, but on a case-by-case basis. 

You can forgo the `makeValidator` logic by choosing a different syntax, e.g. using the validator names and do the argument logic in the `validate method`

task: { validators: [
  [first, 'hi'],
}
and then doing the argument splicing in `validate`

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what's going on with `makeValidator`? What is the reason for `var args = [].slice.call(arguments);`? Slice just removes values before beginning index and after ending index. What values are you removing? And should `makeValidator` be used in place of `first: function (input, term) { ...` ?

Comment: the issue with this is if I store `validators` functionality on the quest object, I can't store the quest data as `JSON` which is what I originally wanted.

Comment: you can choose a different format, you don't have to go with `makeValidator`. An alternative example you could use just validator names and the arguments that they take and do the argument splicing logic in the `validate` call directly.

Example datastructure: task: { validators: [ ['first', 'hi'], ['verbAfterNoun', 'want', 'I'] ] }. That stores both the validator and the initialization arguments and is also serializable